# How to update date column in SQL from jdbcTemplate dynamically?

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I have a column with data type `date` in a table. Now I need to update the column with 30 minutes from the existing date.

For example, if the existing date/time is 04-APR-17 06.20.11.454000000 PM, I need to add 30 minutes to the existing time line 04-APR-17 06.50.11.454000000 PM.

This should be done without selecting the current date. The solution which I found was

```
update table_name 
set column_name = 'SYSDATE - 30/1440';
```

But the problem is I need to keep this 30 minutes as dynamic, which means later I could change to 40 minutes which I ll change from property file.

So is there any way to achieve this using JDBC template without using select statement and also without changing the code (for dynamic minutes).?

//Update:
The minutes can be read from the property file and The coloumn_name sting can be concat from the property file. Which can be actually passed to the update query. This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME= COLUMN_NAME + 10/1440; This is what i was looking for. To update the column time from the existing column time

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thread which sleeps for 30 minutes and calls your SQL that updates the time. Use Joda Time for a better experience with Java dates.

```
while(true){
org.joda.time.DateTime current_date= new org.joda.time.DateTime();
current_date=current_date.withMinuteOfHour(30).
// Call sql
update table_name set column_name=current_date;
Thread.sleep(Property.getProps(CONFIGURED_TIME)*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: This can be used for updating 30 minutes from the current system time. But the requirement is to update the existing time present in column without selecting it. So that only I used **"update table_name set column_name='SYSDATE - 30/1440';"**. Here the value 30/1440 should be passed dynamically to the query. That is what not happening in jdbcTemplate

Comment: so if you're using jdbcTemplate, you can use  jdbcTemplate.update("update table_name set column_name=SYSDATE - "+variable);

Comment: I tried and the got invalid ResultSet access exception. but when i try to update the same from sql developer it is getting updated.                                                                 org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [update table_name set column_name=SYSDATE - 30/1440]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235).

Comment: can you paste the exact code here? Also, remove the ' for SYSDATE. Should be SYSDATE-30/1440 without the apostophes.

Comment: public static int updateTime(String delayTime, String id) {
  int updateCount = 0;
  final String updateTime = "SYSDATE + ".concat(delayTime).concat("/1440");
  try {
   final String sql = messageSource.getMessage("update.time", null, null);
   jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("jdbcTemplate." + id);
   updateCount = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]  {updateTime});
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   throw new DatabaseAccessException("DataBase Exception Occured in updateTime Method", "MPY1666005");
  }
  return updateCount;
 }

Comment: Can you send the exact SQL defined in the sql variable?